# How to run windows form's from Console?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in Windows form application. I have created a Windows form. the entry point of my solution is as per the below

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Boolean bConsole = false;
        for (int nArg = 0; nArg < args.Length; nArg++)
        {
            if (args[nArg].Equals("-Console", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                bConsole = true;
            }
        }

        if (bConsole)
        {
            Form_Main form = new Form_Main();
            form.Form_Main_Console();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form_Main());
        }
    }
```

The application is working fine for windows form. How can I run it from console ?
Can anyone help me regarding that?

Comment: What do you mean by run it from console?

Comment: If you want to pass command line parameters to a winforms app, you send them just like you would to a console app

Comment: I want to run it from command propt with the parameters. Can you please suggest me the command promt for that? I already used  C:\(exe path), but it always opens the main form not goes to the form.Form_Main_Console().

Comment: Thanks nunespascal. It is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile your application to a binary (let's say MyApp.exe).

Now in cmd.exe browse to the same directory (cd /path/to/exe) and type "MyApp.exe cmd1 cmd2".

cmd1 and cmd2 appear as strings in the "string[] args" parameter to your Main function. Do with them however you so please.

Eg:

```
cd %ProgramFiles%/Path/To/App

MyApp -Console whatever
```